# Amazon DynamoDB Atomic Writes

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-dynamodb, aws-lambda

I have a list of Lambda worker functions (say 1000), each running simultaneously and doing its job. To be able to figure out the end result of all workers I have come up with this idea.

Before starting the job and spawning the Lambda worker functions, I save a record in DynamoDB, for example two attributes:

- `total_number_of_jobs`
- `jobs_completed` (set initially to 0)

On finish of each Lambda worker function it will go and increment the attribute `jobs_completed` by one. Then read the record and check if `total_number_of_jobs` equals to `jobs_completed` and if it is, put a record in SQS.

My questions are:

1. Is this a good idea?
2. Would the updates be consistent and atomic? Could there be any race conditions?
3. Any better solution than this?

I would update the counter, `jobs_completed`, in an UpdateItem API call like this:

`SET jobs_completed = jobs_completed + :incr_by` where `incr_by` would be equal to `1`.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

As long as you use DynamoDB atomic counters, like your example shows, and you check the return value of the UpdateItem call instead of running a separate query, then your proposed solution should work fine.

Comment: What do you mean by "check the return value of the UpdateItem call instead of running a separate query". Can you explain?

Comment: Set the `ReturnValues` attribute in the `UpdateItem` call to `"ALL_NEW"` or possibly `"UPDATED_NEW"`. Then the response from the `UpdateItem` call will contain the updated item with the new `jobs_completed` value that you can compare against the `total_number_of_jobs` value to determine if the update you just performed was the last one. You want to do this instead of performing a `GetItem` call after the `UpdateItem` call.

Comment: I see, I understand now. But still even if I do a separate GetItem or Query call shouldn't I get the same value, given that I do a strongly consistent call?

Comment: If you do a separate call you might run into a concurrency issue where two or more processes all think they completed the last job. If that is a problem, then don't do a separate query.

Comment: Thank you Mark, that was enlightening. Never thought of it.